# Strange equality between ceil and floor

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, equality

I was comparing my solution to another's one solution and found this different line which doesn't seem equal at first but they are.

So my question is: How is this equality possible?

```
ceil(k / x) - 1 == floor((k - 1) / x)
```

Comment: that looks like assignment. Not equlity

Comment: I think most modern compiler can already flag this as an error. At least g++  comes with XCode (LLVM based) does it

Comment: I think he's asking a math question.  From a programming standpoint, the question is, why will two programs produce the same results if one says `ceil(k/x)-1` and the other says `floor((k-1)/x)`.  He isn't trying to put the above in his code as a statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming *x* is a positive integer here.

There are two cases to consider: either *k* is a multiple of *x*, or it isn't.

When *k* is a multiple of *x*, then ceil(*k*/*x*) = *k*/*x* since *k*/*x* is an integer.  Also, since (*k*-1)/*x* < *k*/*x* and *k*/*x* is an integer, that means floor((*k*-1)/*x*) will be the next lower integer, i.e. *k*/*x*-1, which equals ceil(*k*/*x*)-1.

When *k* is not a multiple of *x*, then ceil(*k*/*x*) is *k*/*x* rounded up to the next integer, and floor(*k*/*x*) is *k*/*x* rounded down to the next lower integer.  Obviously, ceil(*k*/*x*) - 1 = floor(*k*/*x*).  And since *k* is not a multiple of *x*, it's obvious that (*k*-1/*x*) and *k*/*x* will give the same result when rounding down to the next lower integer; thus, ceil(*k*/*x*) - 1 = floor(*k*/*x*) = floor((*k*-1)/*x*).

Thus, the relation is true in both cases.

It won't be true if `x` or `k` can be a non-integer: try *k*=3, *x*=.01 for instance.  Now ceil(*k*/*x*) = 300, floor((*k*-1)/*x*) = 200.  Or try *k*=4.1, *x*=2: ceil(*k*/*x*) = 3, floor((*k*-1)/*x*) = 1.

[Note: I know this isn't mathematically rigorous.]

Comment: Your proof is correct. Feel free to remove the disclaimer note.